# Failed to resolve endpoint: imaps. No component found with scheme: imaps

Tags: java, maven, apache-camel, osgi, apache-servicemix

I assembled bundle and want to run it in the servicemix. 
I using camel-mail, apache servicemix, and apache felix plugin for maven.
I try:

```
236 | Installed |  80 | 1.0                                | camel-mail-test
karaf@root>bundle:start 236
```

But, I've error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: 
Failed to resolve endpoint: imaps://imap.gmail.com?
consumer.delay=60000&delete=false
&password=***%24a&unseen=true&username=***%40gmail.com 
due to: No component found with scheme: imaps
```

My `pom.xml` dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-mail</artifactId>
        <version>2.16.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core-osgi</artifactId>
        <version>2.16.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>osgi-bundle</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>bundle</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <instructions>
                            <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                            <Bundle-Version>1.0</Bundle-Version>
                            <Bundle-Activator>Main</Bundle-Activator>
                            <Import-Package>
                                *;resolution:=optional
                            </Import-Package>
                        </instructions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Servicemix bundles all installed:

```
karaf@root>la | grep camel
43 | Active   |  50 | 2.16.3                              | camel-core
226 | Active   |  50 | 2.16.3                             | camel-mail
228 | Active   |  80 | 2.16.3                             | camel-core-osgi
karaf@root>la | grep osgi
228 | Active   |  80 | 2.16.3                             | camel-core-osgi
```

In what may be the cause of the error? Please, help

Comment: how do you create your camelcontext ?

Comment: try features:list | grep imaps